# UndeliverableException on blockingGet with timeout in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

When I run a Single as blockingGet with timeout, if a timeout occurs UndeliverableException is thrown. What am I doing wrong, how to resolve this.

```
 Boolean discoverable = checkUserDiscoverability(receiver)
                        .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .blockingGet();


 private Single<Boolean> checkUserDiscoverability(String loopUser) {
        return Single
                .create(emitter -> {
                    Thread.sleep(60*1000);
                    firebaseFirestore
                            .collection(Constants.USERS)
                            .whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), loopUser)
                            .get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        emitter.onSuccess(false);
                                    }
                                    if(task.getResult().isEmpty())
                                        emitter.onSuccess(false);
                                    else
                                        emitter.onSuccess(true);
                                }
                            });
                });
    }
```

**The exception details.**

```
W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:66)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:56)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3082)
W/System.err:     at tasks.worker.FindNewFriendsWorker.doWork(FindNewFriendsWorker.java:62)
```

Comment: Your stacktrace doesn't match up with the code example: `SingleFromCallable` implies `Single.fromCallable` but you have `Single.create`.

Comment: Thats what I get. only when I have a timeout

Comment: Please [enable assembly tracking](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#debug-support) and report back the exception.